# Sql statement to find difference of dates from group of records based on

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

```
ID   firSrvdate   LastSrvdate
----------------------
1    1-12-81  1-15-81
1    1-18-81  1-18-81
1    2-9-81   3-1-81
2    4-2-81   4-5-81
2    8-18-81  8-18-81
2    11-9-81   11-21-81
3    3-12-81  4-15-81
3    7-17-81  8-19-81
```

I need to find the `Mindate` and `Maxdate` for each `ID` under the condition that the difference between the service  should  be less than 90 days

So the result I am expecting is something like this

```
ID  Mindate  MaxDate
-----------
1   1-12-81  3-1-81
2   8-18-81  11-21-81
3   7-17-81  8-19-81
```

Comment: I am sorry , i wasn't able to explain my buisness logic:I need to find the minimum service date and maximum service date for each id,under the condition that the gap between each service period is less than 90 days

Comment: Why, for instance, the results for `ID = 3` show `7-17-81, 8-19-81` and not `3-12-81, 4-15-81` instead (or as well)?

Comment: i need to check if there is 90 gap of service. If the service gap is more than 90 days then the new first service date becomes minimum service date which is the case for id 3.

Comment: I see. My point is, you haven't specified anywhere in your question that you want to start looking from the latest service and go back to earlier ones until a gap of 90+ days is found.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're not sure which pair of dates will fit in the 90 day window we first need to do a join to itself. Once we have that we have to choose which one we want. Using row_Number we can order by the greatest difference. I'm also using maxdate as a tie breaker. Here's what the [intermediate result looks like](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f556/24)

```
SELECT id, 
       mindate, 
       maxdate 
FROM   (SELECT t1.id, 
               t1.mindate, 
               t2.maxdate, 
               Row_number() OVER (partition BY t1.ID 
                                  ORDER BY Datediff(day, t1.mindate, 
                                          t2.maxdate) DESC, t2.maxdate DESC) rn 
        FROM   table1 t1 
               INNER JOIN table1 t2 
                 ON t1.id = t2.id 
        WHERE  Datediff(day, t1.mindate, t2.maxdate) < 90) AS t 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f556/21)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a having clause:

```
select id, min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
from table
group by id
having datediff(day, min(date), max(date) < 90
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the `datediff` and the columns are `MinDate` and `MaxDate` other than that, its the solution.

Comment: @rcdmk  nah as written it will return one answer here's a [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f556/6) of what I mean

Comment: it didnt worked got  the result for Id1 but not for id=2 ,3 as ....id mindate maxdate
1 1981-01-12 1981-01-18